# How to map an Java Servlet only to paths that doesn't have any extension?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I have an Java Servlet that I want to execute only if the path requested DOESN'T have any extension, if the path ends with any extension(css, jsp, js...) it must continue normally, without calling the servlet.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't have such a regex in servlet mapping.

According to servlet [specs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-4-pr-spec/index.html):

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix    is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension    mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"    servlet of the application. In this case the servlet
>   path is the request URI minus the context path and the path
>   info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

However you can have a default filter (/) to handle all such cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to solve this problem with a web filter instead

Comment: A filter is the best approach to do such things. Accept it If my explanation answers your problem.